# When I add a .desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications it appears but doesn't open from Applications menu

Tags: applications, menu, app-shortcuts

So I've made this .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Team Speak 3
Comment=TS
Exec="/home/nicolas/Programs/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh"
Path="/home/nicolas/Programs/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/"
Icon=/usr/share/icons/elementary/apps/128/office-address-book.svg
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

then I've saved it in `~/.local/share/applications` and gave execute permissions (just for my user, 774). I can open that program if I go to that folder and run the file but if I open it from the Applications menu it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Just to be clear: I can see my desktop file in Applications menu. But when I click it, nothing happens.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from Exec and Path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so @shrestha_aj has the answer: I just needed to remove the quotes from Exec and Path. Like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Team Speak 3
Comment=TS
Exec=/home/nicolas/Programs/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
Path=/home/nicolas/Programs/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/
Icon=office-address-book
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Comment: See my edit. Is that correct now?